# How do you implement horizontal candlesticks using the Google Charts API?

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization, google-experiments

I'd like to use the Google Charts API, but they don't seem to support this (at least publicly).

This is what I'd like to replicate (for an internal report): [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaWaD.jpg)

Edit: This is the closest thing that I've found: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#barformatter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way to do exactly the same thing, but you can cheat a bit and get something like this (you can customize as needed for further fine tuning):

[image: Sample]

Basically, I make a stacked bar chart with 6 different series.

1. Dummy (transparent) series
2. Black Lines (so the error bars appear properly)
3. (and 4, 5, 6) Grey, Red, Yellow, Green for the ranges

The Dummy series is transparent, and sets how far up the chart the first bar appears. The black lines series is always 0, and has error bars on it that go from 0 to 100 (the interval columns below). The others represent the data.

This is a bit complex to do by hand, but you can create a javascript function to appropriately distribute the numbers to the various series given a single value. I just put in arbitrary values.

Colors and transparency can be optimized, as can the 'height' of each bar to make it look similar. The axes base lines, and the grid lines can be hidden to make it look better. The legend can also be hidden. I didn't do those figuring you'll fiddle with the code anyhow.

Here is the code:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Label');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Dummy');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Black for Lines');
  data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'interval'});
  data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'interval'});
  data.addColumn('number', 'Grey');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Red');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Yellow');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Green');
  data.addRows([
    ['Target', 65, 0, 0, 100, 15, 00, 00, 00],
    ['Test A', 85, 0, 0, 100, 00, 00, 00, 15],
    ['Test B', 70, 0, 0, 100, 10, 00, 05, 00],
    ['Test C', 10, 0, 0, 100, 00, 15, 00, 00],
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data,
           {isStacked: true,           
            width:600, height:400,
            series: [{color: 'transparent'}, {color: 'black'}, {color: 'grey'}, {color: 'red'}, {color: 'yellow'}, {color: 'green'}]
           }
      );
}
```

Comment: I hadn't considered this approach.  Thanks for your answer!