# Google Charts - Display Area Behind

Tags: google-visualization

I have a chart which displays a column series and two area series (stacked).
I want the areas to display behind the columns. Is this possible?

```
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Day', 'Actual', 'Base','Uplift'],
    ['2013-05-01',140,100,25],
    ['2013-05-07',75,80,22],
    ['2013-05-14',130,105,10],
    ['2013-05-21',110,75,18],
    ['2013-05-28',205,140,25]
  ]);


  // Create and draw the visualization.
  var ac = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
 ac.draw(data, {
    width: 600,
   fontSize:10,
    height: 400,
    colors:['rgb(146,208,80)','rgb(0,112,192)','rgb(184,204,228)'],
    vAxis: { minValue: 0},
    hAxis: {slantedTextAngle: 45},
    seriesType: "bars",
    isStacked:true,
   series: {0:{type:"bars"},1: {type: "area", areaOpacity:.7}, 2: {type: "area", areaOpactiy:1}}
  });
}
```

See fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/MeS2N/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, cannot control the z-index of individual elements within a Google chart.

I tried:

1. Making the bar series come last in the data
2. Moving the bar series to axis 2
3. Moving the other series to axis 2

None of these changed the fact that the bars were written in front in the generated SVG.

There was an issue opened to ask for this feature to be added [in April, 2012](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=863) but it hasn't been addressed yet.

In the meantime, you can use creative solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16703997/1933347):

> ## Option 1: Create custom javascript
>
> You can edit the `svg` that Google Visualization creates with
> javascript. According to [this
> question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482115/with-javascript-can-i-change-the-z-index-layer-of-an-svg-g-element)
> you can change the z-index of elements by moving their order up in the
> SVG. So you'd have to:
>
> 1. Find the svg representing the candlestick elements
> 2. Find out where the last item you want it behind is
> 3. Move the candlestick elements behind that item in the svg
>
> This is obviously a headache (especially if you look at the svg
> formatting of the resulting chart in something like firebug).
>
> ## Option 2: Creative CSS
>
> This is a bit simpler to implement, but has its own set of pitfalls
> (performance, compatibility across browsers, etc.).
>
> Create two charts, one with just the candlesticks, one with the bars
> and candlesticks.
>
> Make sure the scales of each chart are the same.
>
> Use the CSS Z-index to put the chart with the candlesticks below the
> other chart.
>
> Make sure the top chart is transparent, and nothing like labels,
> legends, or other chart junk is duplicated across the charts.
>
> On the top chart, make the candlestick bars invisible (you want them
> there so that the values of the bars are displayed, but you don't want
> to see them as they'd be on top). There are many ways to do this
> (making the line width 0, making the color transparent, or something
> of the sort).
>
> Create an event on the top chart that links the mouseover event to
> select the same series on the bottom chart, so that it looks to the
> user like you have one chart (since they both interact as one chart).
>
> This will hurt performance because you are rendering two charts, and
> transparent backgrounds don't work on some version of IE. It also
> means a lot more work on the actual chart code, because you have to
> line up the charts and make sure that it won't break depending on how
> you change the data.

(Just change the references to "candlesticks" to "areas" as needed -- the concept is the same)

Comment: Thanks for your effort here. This is pretty disappointing! I'll look into these options but I might find it a bit easier to use an alternative reporting package which deals with this natively.